# How to prevent 404 error being shown on Logout?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have a question regarding the logout route. When you look at the [Demo Page](https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/) when the user is logged out, a 404 error is shown in the console, because the CMSPageGuard tries to fetch the non-existing Logout page from the Backend. This is a minor problem but doesn't seem intentional?

More so since the logic in the Logout guard redirects to either 'home' or 'login' in case the logout path doesn't exist.

Is the only workaround to not get the 404 error to add a logout page in the Backend, even though it is never shown?

Answer (score 5):

In short, this is intentional.  It is part of a feature that makes it easy for storefronts that do require the optional logout page to add it in the CMS and it will be picked up out of the box by the Spartacus logout logic.

You are right about what happens under the hood. If you look at the [description of the LogoutGuard in the doc](https://sap.github.io/spartacus/guards/LogoutGuard.html), the overall logic its described like so:

> Takes care of routing the user to a logout page (if available) or redirects to the homepage. If the homepage is protected, the user is redirected to the login route instead.

To verify if a logout page is available, the `LogoutGuard` makes a request for it.  If a logout page is not available, that request returns a 404 and this is what shows up in the browser dev tools.

As for preventing that these errors show in the log, there is for now no configuration that will turn this feature off.  You might explore using a custom `LogoutGuard` and override the `canActivate` function, but I'm not 100% sure this is possible.

Comment: I did already overwrite the Logic in the Logout Guard. It is not the Logout guard making the request for the page, but the CMSPageGuard The LogoutGuard just checks if there is a config for the logout route. 
I think the order of the guards for the logout route (defined in the logout module) is the problem. The Logout guard should execute before the CMSPageGuard. I tried to change the order by defining my own RouterModule.forChild config, but that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, I see there are 2 requests made to the logout page upon logout.  One seems to come from LogoutGuard, the other from CMSPAgeGuard.  If you manage to override the LogoutGuard so it doesn't attempt to redirect to a `logout` cms page, you could also remove `CMSPageGuard` from the overridden logout route config.  I think `CMSPageGuard` might not be used in the scenario where you never want to redirect to a logout cms page.  Hopefully, that should eliminate the 404 errors.

Comment: I know this is more an Angular than a Spartacus question, but i tried to change the route config already, but i the guard is still activated. Is it possible to remove guards from already defined routes?

  `RouterModule.forChild([{ path: null, canActivate: [LogoutGuard], component: PageLayoutComponent, data: { cxRoute: 'logout' },},`

Comment: So far, I don't think this is possible.  I did some attempts to override the route configuration but I had no success.